# Error: Cannot parse configuation files:

Tags: bitcoin-core

I've been running Bitcoin Core forever on my Windoze 10 desktop and recently started getting the following on a reboot.  WSJT-X is a ham radio application on my computer that isn't even running.

[image]

Comment: Does your configuration reference WSJTX? How do Bitcoin Core and WSJTX relate in your setup? Could WSJTX perhaps have registered itself as the default application for the `.conf` file type? The error message says that the problem is that it cannot communicate with WSJTX. Have you tried what happens when you turn on WSJTX before starting Bitcoin Core? (Assuming that WSJTX and Bitcoin Core are supposed to interact.)

Comment: WTF...  this is my bitcoin.conf file.   This app totally took it over.  This is a HAM radio application that has nothing to do with bitcoin.

Unable to communicate with the WSJTX process.
  UDP Port : 7831
  IP Address : 127.0.0.1
  Values read from WSJTX config file...
    C:\Users\TAC\AppData\Local\WSJT-X - Slice-A\WSJT-X - Slice-A.ini
WSJTX Detected Instance...
  Process Window Title : WSJT-X - Slice-A   v2.5.4   by K1JT, G4WJS, K9AN, and IV3NWV
  Process Command Line : D:\WSJT\wsjtx\bin\wsjtx.exe  --rig-name=Slice-A
Decode alerts and logging will be unavailable until corrected.